# NGINX server not applying the CSS files

Tags: css, reactjs, nginx, web, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app based React App. I am currently serving it using NGINX. I generated the build directory and serving it as a root in NGINX. My NGINX conf currently looks like this:

```
http {

         server {
                listen 80;

                root /home/react-app/build;

                index index.html;

                location / {
                        try_files $uri /index.html;
                }

        }
}
```

However when I load the page, the JS and html files are loading. However the CSS is not being applied. Also, when I checked the network tab in browser developer tools, I see that the CSS files are properly being loaded with http status 200. However the CSS is not being applied. Please help me, this is bugging me since 2 days.

Comment: Check the `Content-Type` HTTP header of your CSS file response in the DevTools, what is it value?

Comment: Oh yes. Its actually text/plain. How to resolve this?

Comment: You should have `mime.types` file in your nginx config directory, add `include mime.types;` before the `server` block. If there are no such file in your config directory, take it from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nginx/nginx/master/conf/mime.types).

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thanks!