# CSS doesn't work when site is served over nginx

Tags: html, css, nginx, web, static

When I was developing a static website I used VS Code and Live Server (Windows machine).
Site seemed to work fine.

However, when I moved files to my CentOS machine to serve the site over nginx, site loads normally and bootstrap carousel works but my custom CSS that fixes few things around the site doesn't seem to have an effect.

If I open files statically from Firefox (Files -> Open File) on my CentOS machine, CSS works normally.

I checked the networking tab in Developers tools and .css file is transfered to the browser but for some reason it just won't work when site is served over nginx.

1 other thing that I noticed is in networking tab (when served over nginx) is that when I click on css file and go to Response -> Response Payload all of the css instructions are grey as if css was commented but in reality there are no comments.

**EDIT**
networking tab says nginx marked css file with content type text/plain.

Comment: How is your path in the .html files ?... somethimes the names are with capital letters and some servers serve the file others don't

Comment: @Nemesius it's all lower case

Comment: @Nemesius that's not even the point because css file is sent by nginx to browser

Comment: Read comments under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265060/nginx-server-not-applying-the-css-files) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nginx.conf file add following inside server context:

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

Comment: I lost almost 6 hours until I found this. Thank you